# Как менять url в интерфейсе. Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, интерфейс

Имеется такой интерфейс

```
@GET ("weather?q=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather();
```

А также базовый URL

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
```

Программа работает, но я бы хотел менять url в интерфейсе, чтобы получать данные других городов.
Пробовал такие сценарии:

```
@GET ("weather?{q}=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Path("q") String location);

@GET ("{weather?q}=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Path("weather?q") String location);

@GET ("weather?q={location}&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Path("location") String location);

@GET ("weather?q={location}&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Query("location") String location);

@GET ("weather?{q}=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Query("q") String location);

@GET ("{weather?q}=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(@Query("weather?q") String location);
```

Метод networkRequest

```
    public void networkRequest(){
    tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
    tvTemperature = findViewById(R.id.tv_temperature);
    tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    tvHumidity = findViewById(R.id.tv_humidity);
    location = "Москва";
    NetworkRequest.getRequest()
            .getWeatherApi()
            .getWeather(location)
            .enqueue(new Callback<WeatherMain>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<WeatherMain> call, Response<WeatherMain> response) {
                    WeatherMain weatherMain = response.body();
                    tvLocation.setText(weatherMain.getName());
                    //Проверяю температуру на положительные и отрицательные значения и вывожу
                    int temp = (int) weatherMain.getMain().getTemp();
                    if (temp > 0) {
                        tvTemperature.setText(String.valueOf("+" + temp + "°"));
                    } else {
                        tvTemperature.setText(String.valueOf("-" + temp + "°"));
                    }
                    //Вывожу влажность воздуха
                    tvHumidity.setText("Влажность - " + String.valueOf(weatherMain.getMain().getHumidity()) + "%");
                    //Вывожу описание погоды
                    String s = toUpperLetter(weatherMain.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                    tvDescription.setText(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<WeatherMain> call, Throwable t) {
                    showToast("Не удалось получить данные");
                }
            });

}
```

Приложение или вылетает или выполняет `onFailure()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно делаете запрос. Ваш запрос должен выглядеть примерно так

```
@GET("weather")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(
    @Query("q") String city,
    @Query("units") String units,
    @Query("APPID") String appid,
    @Query("lang") String lang
);
```

Я думаю вам лучше стоит ознакомиться с [документацией Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 1):

Данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135768/285996) от Sergei Buvaka помог мне. Я изменил интерфейс таким образом

```
public interface WeatherAPI  {

//@GET ("weather?q=Махачкала&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7&lang=ru")

@GET("weather")
Call<WeatherMain> getWeather(
        @Query("q") String city,
        @Query("units") String units,
        @Query("APPID") String appid,
        @Query("lang") String lang
);
```

}

Создал переменные

```
String keyLocation = "Махачкала";
String keyUnits = "metric";
String keyAPPID = "0b.......712a7";
String keyLang = "ru";
```

И передал их в качестве параметра

```
 NetworkRequest.getRequest()
            .getWeatherApi()
            .getWeather(keyLocation, keyUnits, keyAPPID, keyLang)
            .enqueue(new Callback<WeatherMain>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<WeatherMain> call, Response<WeatherMain> response) {}
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<WeatherMain> call, Throwable t) {}
```

P.S тестировал для других городов, меняя значение переменной **keyLocation** и это работает

Comment: APPID свой не нужно только светить